# Enable graphics card in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, nvidia-optimus

I recently bought a new laptop with following configuration

- CPU: Intel i5 2450
- RAM: 8 GB DDR3
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 520 1GB

I've setup a virtual machine using VirtualBox with Windows 7 as guest. I want to use my (host's) graphics card in it but the virtual machine is only showing 128 MB of video memory.

I am using Bumblebee and start the virtual machine using

```
 $ optirun VBoxManage startvm "Windows 7"
```

Please suggest me how should I use my graphics card for 3D acceleration in virtual machine.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As with almost everything in a virtual machine, the graphics card is virtual too.  You can still access the hardware graphics acceleration, but it is to a limited extent only (one of the limitations is the max of 128 MB RAM.)

To make use of those 3D features available choose *3D acceleration* in the *Display* settings of your virtual machine. In addition you will also need the [Guest Additions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtualbox/22745#22745) to provide a driver for the virtual graphics adapter.

For the **experimental** feature of passing a PCI card to Virtual Box (which may work with few graphic cards only) see:

- [How to use NVIDIA GeForce M310 on Ubuntu 12.10 running as guest in VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202926/how-to-use-nvidia-geforce-m310-on-ubuntu-12-10-running-as-guest-in-virtualbox)

Comment: Thanks,isn't there exist any other option to make full use of graphics card in vm.What about kvm-qmenu?

Answer (score 6):

To check if your Ubuntu 12.10 or 13.04 guest is using 3D acceleration

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

You should see something like this

```
Not software rendered: no
Not blacklisted: yes
GLX fbconfig: yes
GLX texture from pixmap: yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program: yes
GL fragment program: yes
GL vertex buffer object: yes
GL framebuffer object: yes
GL version is 1.4+: yes
Unity 3D supported: no
```

If you see “Not software rendered” and “Unity 3D supported” both say no. This means Unity is using slow LLVMpipe.

To enable 3D supported, fist you will need to update linux-headers

```
uname -r
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Now insert vitualbox guest iso from devices and to install manually

```
cd /media
ls
cd username
ls
cd VBOX*
ls
sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

Insert vboxvideo to /etc/modules

```
sudo nano /etc/modules
```

Add “vboxvideo” at the end of the file

```
loop
lp
vboxvideo
```

Reboot the machine

```
sudo reboot
```

Check ”Not software rendered” and “Unity 3D supported” are enabled or not after rebooting

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

The next thing you want to do is to increase video memory. Look for .vbox file

```
nano /home/username/VirtualBox VMs/ubuntu/ubuntu.vbox
```

Replace

```
<Display VRAMSize=”128″ monitorCount=”1″ accelerate3D=”true” accelerate2DVideo=”false”/>
```

To

```
<Display VRAMSize=”256″ monitorCount=”1″ accelerate3D=”true” accelerate2DVideo=”false”/>
```

from http://namhuy.net/951/how-to-fix-slow-performance-ubuntu-13-04-running-in-virtualbox.html

Comment: Op isn't using an Ubuntu guest.

Answer (score 2):

Under Ubuntu-64b, I assigned 3G-RAM,  256MB for video, processor 2D/3D accelerator enable(also IO APIC to use up to 3 core processor) in Vista 32b. One more thing... Install DirectX  All working... and the sound quality is a lot better than the one I got when running under Wine in my old laptop.