# Is it possible to use my real graphic card on a virtual machine?

Tags: graphics, virtualbox, vmware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use NVIDIA GeForce M310 on Ubuntu 12.10 running as guest in Virtualbox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202926/how-to-use-nvidia-geforce-m310-on-ubuntu-12-10-running-as-guest-in-virtualbox)

I am asking this question because I'm just curious. When I install a virtual machine by using [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or [VMware](http://www.vmware.com/), is it use my real graphical card? If not, is it possible to use it on a virtual machine?

Comment: I would like to comment that this question is more suitable for the [su] site in my opinion.

Comment: related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/202926/how-to-use-nvidia-geforce-m310-on-ubuntu-12-10-running-as-guest-in-virtualbox

Comment: It makes no sense to refer to another "related" or "similar" question, because technologies are moving forward rapidly everyday, some questions that were impossible to answer in the past may be answered today; some answers that were correct in the past may be incorrect today. It is true especially in Linux world. So every question is a new question, there is no such thing as "duplicate" question in most cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, VMWare Workstation has the ability of 3D on VMs, it does not exactly lets the guest system use the card, but does some kind of mapping of the requests of the guest to OpenGL requests on the host (at least in the last time I checked).
It has limited 3D ability though.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not and it <del>is also</del> may not be possible to connect your graphics card directly to virtual machine.

I read a long discussion in [virtualbox forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=16), why it can't be done. But it said, those software emulates hardware and drivers (to be used in guest) are written according to that. There are severe limitation to emulate a 3D graphics card because the drivers are closed source.

I found something interesting - https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=16