# Enabling graphics card Nvidia GT 540M in Virtual box in Ubuntu 14.04, hosted on Windows 10

Tags: nvidia, virtualbox, cuda

I am interested and struggling to learn and work on CUDA and attempting to setup a whole system to get it ready, while I already have spent plenty of time on this.

**Setup:**
Asus K53SV notebook- https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/K53SV/specifications/,
Windows 10,
Nvidia GT 540M,
Virtualbox(latest version),
Ubuntu 14.04.

**Problems**:
How to enable Nvidia card in virtual box?

Installing appropriate nvidia driver and cuda tool kit?

Is there also a way to define virtual nvidia card in virtualbox, which can be used in accordance with CUDA development tool kit?

I would really appreciate any kind of help and suggestions in this regard.

Comment: Check [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/256853/400278) out it just might lead you to the right answer.

Comment: Untested but provided the graphics card is **not in use** in the host (i.e. have the possibility to switch to the Intel Core i integrated graphics), and the Nvidia GT540M supports this (which I don't know) we may be able to pass through the PCI to the VM: http://askubuntu.com/questions/202926/how-to-use-nvidia-geforce-m310-on-ubuntu-12-10-running-as-guest-in-virtualbox

Comment: I gave up on working on CUDA toolkit on ubuntu14.04 in VM. No I am having Ubuntu 14.04 and Cuda toolkit 7.5-18 installed (atleast I think so). Now... while i try to make the sample i am having the following Warning message "simpleGLES is not supported on Linux x86_64 - waiving". Any suggestion to solve this problem.